# Using a video to apply texture to a pre-existing 3D model

Tags: texturing, video

Suppose that we have a 3D model of an object and have it machined and painted in real life. We then place a camera and the object on a rotating stand. After that, we can capture the video of the object and at the same time, rotate that object.
We know have the 3D model of the object and a video that captures the object with an uneven rotational speed, but at a fixed distance away from the object [we can assume that the object has a shape with rotational symmetry]).

How can I use the video to apply texture around the virtual object?

I have tried to use linear projection for one frame of the video and the projection got somehow wrapped around the object instead of only being projected to the front half of the object.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You could do something like texture paint, using photos of the object as stencil brush. The key here would be to use the exact same camera settings in Blender as the camera positioned IRL. Then it could be automated with Python, and the only problem remaining is to reliably rotate the object precisely. There are tools for that in machining.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to split video into image sequence, use some photogrammetry tool to generate textured mesh and that use Bake > Selected to Active? If you add some screens of your case it would be easier to offer adequate solution.

Comment: Hi Markus,
Thank you for your suggestion.
I have redone the experiment and got a video with the object being rotated with a precise angular velocity. How can I ask Blender to do some averaging on the regions that are captured in more than 1 frame?

Comment: @ThianDanielIskandar maybe first draw with opacity 100%, and then repeat the process with less opacity? I would do it lazily, opacity 100% first, then opacity 50%, 25%, and then maybe try from another side, opacity 1% and run the loop like a hundred times (as long as I see some gradual improvements in the shared areas)